# RMarkdown: Adding LaTeX dependencies to YAML metadata using R commands

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to add metadata to an RMarkdown document using R commands.

The use case is to provide a helper function to users of my package to load the required package when outputting results from the package.

For example, I want to use a command in an R chunk to add latex dependencies to my header:

```
asis_output(cat("---\n  header-includes:\n    - \\usepackage{unicode-math}"))
```

This works fine if the RMarkdown document doesn't already have `header-includes` or `include:\n  in_header:` fields, but it has no effect if either of those is already present in the document. Simply calling the `latex_dependency` function does nothing (I assume this function needs to be passed to `render` and can't be used when knitting with RStudio, but I'm not sure because its use isn't documented at all as far as I can see).

Is there any way add additional commands to the header LaTeX (and/or HTML) header from an R chunk?